# Angular 4, how to fix 404 error for html files in "simple deployment"?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I am trying to deploy my application in the way specified in the section "Simplest deployment possible" of [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#dev-deploy).
I have created the project by the quick start setup. To deploy the application I have changed following files:
index.html, main.ts, systemjs.config.server.js with path as https://unpkg.com/
But I am getting 404 error for html templates. For ex:

`GET http://localhost:3001/app.component.html 404 (Not Found) zone.js:2616`
My application is running fine when I revert to default setup.
Specifically following section in systemjs.config:

```
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I am serving by `npm start` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Angular4, I have also got this error sometimes.
Resolved by adding this in main.ts:
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';